# Convert php script into a Joomla Module 3.2.3

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-module

I wrote this php script with an html form that sends all the data entered by email. how to convert it into a module for joomla 3.2.3? I searched around but unfortunately I have not found anything.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table border="0">
<caption align="center"><h3>FORM</h3></caption>
<tr>
  <td>Your Mail:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="sender_mail" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Name:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="name" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Description:</td>
  <td><textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="description" style="resize:none"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Address:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="address" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Image:</td>
  <td><input type="file" name="attachFile" /></td>
</tr>
  <tr><td><h4>Images:</h4></td></tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="file" name="attachFile1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="file" name="attachFile2" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="file" name="attachFile3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="file" name="attachFile4" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="file" name="attachFile5" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="send" value="send" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
$to = "email@example.com";
$subject= "subject";
$todayis = date("l, F j, Y, g:i a") ;
$name = $_POST['name'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$email = $_POST['sender_mail'];
$message = "
Date: $todayis
Name: $name
description:\n$description\n
address: $address";

  $mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";
         $headers = "From: $email\r\n" .
         "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
            "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
            " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
         $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
            "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
            "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
         $message . "\n\n";
         foreach($_FILES as $userfile)
         {
            $tmp_name = $userfile['tmp_name'];
            $type = $userfile['type'];
            $name = $userfile['name'];
            $size = $userfile['size'];
            if (file_exists($tmp_name))
            {
               if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name))
               {
                  $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');
                  $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));
                  fclose($file);
                  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
               }
               $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                  "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
                  " name=\"{$name}\"\n" .
                  "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
                  " filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
               $data . "\n\n";
            }
         }
         $message.="--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
   echo "Mail sent successfully.";
else
   echo "Error in mail";
}
?>
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Start reading the Joomla documentation on how to get started with a module. The start developing it and if you run into a problem, ask your question again with a specific coding related issue

Comment: Maybe you can start having a look at the Forms extensions: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms

Comment: I have read the documentation, but I do not understand how to split my code into multiple files of the module joomla.

Comment: looks at how other default modules have been written. you will pick up the idea very easily

Answer (score -1):

Here is some Documentation on how to create a simple module for **Joomla 2.5+**.

Generally, modules have around 3 files by default... but they can have more based on your Joomla.

File Structure.

mod_yourmodule.php (**This would really have the base code for redirecting using to the default.php file... See the mod_login.php file for the default Joomla module.**)
mod_yourmodule.xml (**this would have all the author information and the name of your module again about a couple of times... again, look at the default mod_login.xml**)

tmpl/default.php (**This would have most of your code... what you just paste at the top**).

for starters.
- Joomla is based on PHP and works mostly the same way... so, you can have the same form above and post it to the current page and use jRequest to get all the input values.
http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Retrieving_and_Filtering_GET_and_POST_requests_with_JRequest::getVar

Now... i am sure you would have gotten to a point where your module is somewhat working and you can ask for support back here... if not, you can always use something like Rsform to get a form on the go in Seconds.

Comment: Again, you are referring someone to OLD coding standards. The OP has specifically said they're using Joomla 3.2. There is even a big blue notice at the top of the link you have provided saying JRequest is deprecated.